# Specifying sorting

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-order-by

I have a set of POCO models that are nested to various levels and were generated by reverse engineering an existing database with the entity framework powertools. At one point I have a model that looks something like this:

```
public partial class Model
{
    public Model 
    {
        this.subModels = new List<subModel>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<subModel> submodels { get; set; }
}
```

and a submodel that looks something like this:

```
public partial class subModel
{
    public int subModelID { get; set; }
    public int foo1 { get; set; }
    public int foo2 { get; set; }
}
```

What I need is for the `subModels` in `Model` to be ordered by `foo1` then `foo2` rather than by the primary key `subModelID`, but I can't figure out the best way to do this. There doesn't seem to be a place where I can tell it to retrieve the data from the database already in that order and when I try to use the `subModels` property on `Model` I can't seem to use any Linq on it. Just about the only thing I can do is use `GetEnumerator()` and enumerate through it in whatever order the database spat them out in.

I'm using MySQL if that make any difference.

Update: Okay, I can use Linq, I just forgot to add the `using` statement. It's been a long week! Still, I'd like to know if it's possible to tell EF to query the data in the right order in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to explicitly load your navigation property, you could do something like this:

```
Model model;

context.Entry(model)
   .Collection(k => k.submodels )
   .Query()
   .OrderBy(p => p.foo1 )
   .ThenBy(p=> p.foo2 )
   .Load();
```

It's kind of cumbersome but would work. Seems like it would be just as easy to order them when you want to use them though.